# Resending webform submission doesn't use custom mail template

Tags: webforms, emails

I created a custom webform email template named webform-mail-1.tpl.php that is used when a user submits a webform.  The problem is, if someone modifies that submission and wants to resend that submission by email, the email uses the default template instead of the custom one ...

Does anybody have an idea as to why this happens ?  I didn't read anything about needing a separate template for emails that are sent again ...

Thanks !

Comment: Make sure you are using the active theme while submitting webform first time and while editing webform. This seems similar https://www.drupal.org/node/1126242

Comment: YES !  My admin theme was using a different theme than my default theme, that's why the template used was the default one ... that also explains some problems I had in the past trying to dpm some variables as an admin and not seing anything printed on the screen.  Thank you very much !

Comment: keep the same webform template in your theme also. Enjoy! Love Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site was using two different themes and webform was submitted from the front end theme(first theme) and back end theme(second theme)
The problem was that the webform template was present in the front end theme and not in the back end theme. So that's why when the user submitted the webform once the email uses the custom template.and when the user edit the webform under the back end theme the webform custom template is not present in this theme so the webform was using the default template.
Fix : Keep the similar custom template in both themes.